# Nautilus description versus /usr/share/applications file directory

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, .desktop

When using Nautilus and I navigate to the `/usr/share/applications` directory I get a listing of the meta data that is extracted from all of the .desktop files that live in that directory.

So the file in my example called `"Oracle Java 7 Runtime"` in Nautilus translates to the file `JB-java.desktop` which I took a wild guess at. In Nautilus the properties dialog does not reveal the name of that file, so its a hit and miss approach to get the file name.

Is there a better way? Short of looking for the string "Oracle Java 7 Runtime" in all of the files in the directory which is a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reply by @green7 is OK if you like the terminal.

However, this can be done directly from Nautilus, although it requires a script.

1. I have written the script for you. I don't know how to attach a script to this answer, so please [download it from my file area](https://www.dropbox.com/s/joxfzo7xjb9p59u/Show%20.desktop%20name).
2. Save this file to the following folder:
   `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`
   This means the folder `nautilus-scripts` within `.gnome2` inside your home folder. Note the `.` in front of `.gnome2`; this means it is a hidden file, and you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> within Nautilus to be able to see it. If the `nautilus-scripts` folder doesn't exist, create it.
3. Once you have saved the script there, you need to make it executable. Right-click the file in Nautilus, select Properties > Permissions > Allow executing file as program > Close.
4. Finally, you have to close Nautilus and re-open it (you may have to log out and in again, although I don't think you do).

Now, to use the script, use Nautilus to find those desktop files again. Select one or more of them > right-click > Scripts > Show .desktop name.

An example is shown below.

[image: Example of three desktop files.].

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time, this example will set me on an adventure of Nautilus scripting.

Comment: Doogfar, I have found Nautilus scripting highly useful. For example, I have a scripts to do: MD5, SHA1 and SHA256 sums for files; open as administrator; and create hard links. Here's something for you to try: right-click anywhere in Nautilus > Scripts > Open Scripts Folder > Show more details.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script to do so:

```
#! /bin/bash
# is: Inline file search script
# Save as: /usr/bin/is and mark executable

filename="$1"
echo -n "Enter the command name: "
commandName=""
while [ -z "$commandName" ];
do
read commandName
done

exec $commandName $filename
```

To add auto-completion to the script:

```
# Save as: /etc/bash/completion.d/is

_is()
{
  local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    if [[ ${cur} == * ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(find ./ -maxdepth 1 -iname "*${cur}*" | cut -d '/' -f 2) ) 
        return 0
    fi
}
complete -F _is is
```

It is an inline file search utility.

Suppose you’re in a directory having a lot of files. You want to search for a file but you remember it’s name only in bits and pieces.

For example, if you just remember `oracle`, all you have to do is:

- Browse to the directory

```
cd /path/to/the/directory
```

- Type the following and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>:

```
is oracle
```

- It will show you the list of all the files having `oracle` in their names.
- You can then modify the argument and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to select a particular file.
- Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select a program to open that file.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution, which also expands my Linux knowledge, thank you for the lesson